# Xcode ixuserpresentableerrordomain error when running code on simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, simulator

When ever I run any project on xcode simulator, I get error message:

```
This App could not be installed at this time.
Domain=ixuserpresentableerrordomain code=1
```

I tried:

```
Hardware > Erase all Contents and Settings.
```

But with no luck.

I'm testing on a virtual machine with `Mac Catalina v10.15 beta` and `xcode V 11.0 build : 11A420a` .

Comment: have you found any solution?

Comment: @Harshavardhan Nope !